# Remove single stylesheet by ID class if mobile max width detected

Tags: jquery

several desktop / laptop version stylesheets are linked and I embedded my mobile version css.

I do not have full control of the website so i can not touch the main html / css files .

I can only add additional HTML/CSS/Java or Jquery to the site

Since i dont have control the only way i seeing getting past this issue is using Jquery to remove a single stylesheet by ID name, but ONLY when a mobile device max-width 980 is detected.

I have searched google extensively and haven't seen this question asked or answered, so i come for you all for some help.

so wondering if there is a way to adjust this `jQuery('#mainStyleSheet').remove();`
so that it only removes the #mainStylesheet if max width of device is 980

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of removing, you could just use `.prop()` to disable the stylesheet.

```
$('#mainStyleSheet').prop('disabled',true)
```

As far as detecting the mobile device is concerned, you could `navigator.userAgent`

If you'd like a solution using width, try `window.outerWidth`. I'm not sure how reliable it is.

```
if(window.outerWidth < 980) {
    $('#mainStyleSheet').prop('disabled',true)
}
```

Comment: dont know anything about jquery , so i haven't heard of either of those. would this be correct then ?  $('#mainStyleSheet').navigator.userAgent('disabled',true) to remove that particular stylesheet when mobile is detected

Comment: @user2200854 - i have updated my answer.. may be thats all you need.